# Is there a RHEL-based Linux for home desktop/laptop use excepting CentOS?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel

I want to try a very stable Fedora/RHEL - based Linux.

I learned that Fedora is meant for **developers** (not home users like me), and its purpose is to stay very up-to-date,  therefore to update specific programs frequently, even go to a new system version twice a year. While it is said based on Red Hat, Fedora is in fact a newer, less-stable version than Red Hat (although arguably more stable than many other distros) - or the other way around: Red Hat is based on an older, more stable, long-term and better tested version of Fedora.

I have learned that there are some non-commercial Linux systems based directly on the more stable, more long-term Red Hat itself. One is **CentOS**: but is meant for servers, not home users. Another one I looked at is **Scientific Linux**: only it is meant for institutions and labs, and not only came with a very old KDE4 desktop (the risks I have to take), but it lacks basic features like support for ntfs partitions.

CentOS might be the thing, but **is there a homeuser-meant Linux based on RHEL-stable, as an alternative to CentOS?**

Comment: @Christopher - Yes. But RHEL-based distros there are not listed as such, there is a [Fedora-based list](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?basedon=Fedora#simple). You see the problem. Centos and RHEL are listed as based on Fedora, when in fact Fedora latest is newer and - if not properly rolling - very fast updating. So, they are based on an older stable Fedora that is and was never to be found, because under that name it was always fast-updating. Korora  seems closer to my homeuser criteria, but in fact it is strictly following Fedora's updates. (I already use Fedora).

Comment: I disagree about Fedora being for developers. I'm running desktop PC with Fedora 25 (yeah, need to upgrade to 27...) + KDE with much convenience for couple of years now. Mainly using it for web, media, mail, graphics (Krita, GIMP), disc burning, downloading and all that fun, including sysops. Very stable after last updates it received. I'll also add music production and see how it goes then... but that needs to wait until I've upgraded. Also: used CentOS 6&7 as desktops - also great, but require more time and work from user.

Comment: Been using Debian on a laptop for many years. Does everything I need - home and professional.

Comment: This one's not fedora based, but if you want something that's supposed to "just be" on the computer and work, you might find SolusOS to be for you. It's kind of rolling, but made to "just work" without having to tinker with it. Something to consider if fedora is too fast-paced with its upgrade cycle.

Comment: @Mioriin - I know about Solus. For some odd reason I cannot install it. The initial update after installation invariably breaks the system on my machine.

Comment: @yahol - this seems it will be closed as off-topic. I guess I agree with you. Fedora it's what I use now, I like it a lot.  I find it odd though new kernels being installed every two days.  It is not only for developers but is it **meant** for home-users.

Comment: @cipricus actually i forgot to add: Fedora is used as a testing ground for RedHat and this kinda explains rapid updates of everything, while CentOS is meant as a stable, free/community driven production environment one can use commercially. I guess Fedora is good for testing new cutting-edge kernel features and such.

Comment: @Christopher - I have removed what in the question **might** have suggested a demand for an opinion-based answer (when it was **not**): the question provided the **context** of my demand, and that was based on my opinions; but I was **not** asking for **an opinion-based-answer**, on the contrary. I was (and am) asking about a simple **fact**: "are there or are there not other RHEL-based distros except Centos?" - Now I have removed the context and the risk that people (who didn't have the patience to read all that long story) would jump to wrong conclusions.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - please see my above comment on reopening this.

Comment: @Jesse_b - please see my above comment on reopening this.

Comment: @G-Man - please see my above comment on reopening this

Comment: @isaac - please see my above comment on reopening this

Comment: **I need this reopened because I want to post my own answer.**

Comment: How can a question starting with **"is there"** be asking for opinion-based answers instead of facts?

Comment: @Christopher - I would like to post an answer: To the part of the question *Is there a RHEL-based distro meant for home users?* - the answer is NO. But: *Can be CentOS adapted for home users?* the answer is YES: during installation one can install a desktop (Gnome3+Classic or KDE4) and with just office and multimedia without developer or advanced server tools. Also, I would provide some tips on how to make it more homey.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a no cost RHEL Developer Subscription... 1 per user.  Google on "Developer Subscription". You don't necessarily have to be a "developer" to get this.

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/03/31/no-cost-rhel-developer-subscription-now-available/

Comment: Yup, using it myself at home, as a lab and playground for learning in professional context. It runs, however, on old PowerEdge server, headless, minimal installation with virtualization. Haven't tried it as a home desktop, but it can serve almost any other system as a VM with remote desktop graphics, which works well on gigabit lan.

Comment: Note that this subscription entitles you to run on one physical and 100 virtual machines.

Comment: I guess that is a good answer, but not better than just saying CentOS. I would like to provide an answer myself on that (the question is still on hold though), because now I see that during the installation procedure one can avoid selecting all the "development" stuff and can just select  the desktop (Gnome3 or KDE4) and the office/multimedia stuff, which provides something very close to what was asked. (I guess RHEL also asks you to select what to install in the same way.)